# HTML/PHP/JS - Upload File while filling Form

Tags: php, javascript, html, file, upload

i have a form with a Photo Upload Input. I want the picture to be uploaded before submitting the form to speed up the submit.

the form should be able to upload multiple files and should show a progressbar + preview.

how i can do this?

MetinKale38

Comment: This is actually very complex. I spent an entire week developing something. fineuploader.com Works great and has some basic php examples to get you started.

Comment: it seems pretty simple, but fineuploader is not for free

Comment: @metinkale38 It is open-sourced (on Github) and licensed by default under GPL v3.  So, if you GPL v3 works for you, it is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily now in HTML5 using XMLHttpRequest with a multipart form and the file element. XMLHttpRequest now supports progress events which you can handle in your Javascript code.  Here is a link to an excellent article with detail and code examples [http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/).

Note that your PHP code must still treat each file independently, but that is transparent to your JavaScript - it will simply make multiple posts to the server.

Comment: seems to be the only method without server-side modification, is that right?

Comment: I don't know if it's the **only** method, but this method will work without any special mods or packages in PHP. I have used it to replace a previous implementation that only supported a single file and was able to use the PHP code unchanged.